# Can I change a default property in appengine model?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I didn't read the doc enough before starting this, my mistake.
I have :

```
class A(db.Model):
  date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

I would prefer `auto_now=True` instead. Can I just change it ? I know that a change won't affect existing data (i.e it won't magically change the date of objects in the datastore to their last update date).

Bu what will happen to entities that were created with the `auto_now_add=True` ? Is a model transformation like that permitted ? Or will this just affect new objects ?

I can reformulate my questions if I am not clear, don't hesitate to ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a model transformation. `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` are applied entirely in the Python db client, not at the datastore level. You can change it whenever you like, and all entities that you modify after making that change (as long as you're using the new code) will update the date field when `put()` is called.